# Why do some PHP programmers use a double backslash in their namespaces instead of a single one?

Tags: php, namespaces

While scanning some library code today, I've seen it several times: Instead of declaring a `Namespace\Like\This`, it's `Done\\Like\\This`.

Could somebody please enlighten me – whats the reason behind this?

All I can images that it's either something framework specific (which I don't believe), or it's a strange form of escaping that I don't understand.

Comment: There's no reason to do it when declaring a namespace; but if you have a define a string that will be used to reference a namespaced object, then you need to escape each "\" in your string using "\\"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use double backslash when you're referencing the class name in a string, eg: `$className = "Foo\\Bar".` This is prevent the escaping of characters, a familiar example would be a newline `echo "Hello World\n";` If you had two backslashes it would print "Hello World\n" rather than "Hello World" with a new line.