# What is the difference between \\ and \ in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I've been following a few Laravel 5.8 tutorials where the instructor used `\\` when creating controller, `php artisan make:controller Admin\\UserController -r`. I tried making another resource controller, expect I used 1 backslash, `php artisan make:controller Admin\AnotherController` and it did pretty much the same thing. What is the difference between using `\\` and `\`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some PHP programmers use a double backslash in their namespaces instead of a single one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346705/why-do-some-php-programmers-use-a-double-backslash-in-their-namespaces-instead-o) - This isn't Laravel specific.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes it does. Thank you. I don't now why it didn't pop up on search tho.